# Error C2113 when compiling C code

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-errors

I have no experience with C whatsoever (though I use C# a lot) but am looking to compile some C code:

http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/stochastic-searching/cryptanalysis-bifid-cipher/

When I use the Developer Command Prompt in VS2015 to compile it with cl.exe, I hit an error:

```
c:\simple>cl bifidcrack.c
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.23026 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

bifidcrack.c
bifidcrack.c(113): error C2113: '-': pointer can only be subtracted from another
 pointer
bifidcrack.c(114): error C2113: '-': pointer can only be subtracted from another
 pointer

c:\simple>
```

Why is this failing to compile? Others (in the page comments) have supposedly compiled it without any issues.

C:\simple contains:

```
C:\simple>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is AA86-3F24

 Directory of C:\simple

22/10/2015  02:50    <DIR>          .
22/10/2015  02:50    <DIR>          ..
12/10/2015  12:06             4,491 bifidcrack.c
12/10/2015  12:06         7,301,392 qgr.h
12/10/2015  12:06               574 scoreText.c
12/10/2015  12:06                44 scoreText.h
               4 File(s)      7,306,501 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  14,560,649,216 bytes free

C:\simple>
```

As requested, here are the lines in question:

```
char *bifidDecipher(char *key, int period, char *text, char *result, int len){
    int i, j;
    char a,b; /* the digram we are looking at */
    int a_ind,b_ind;
    int a_row,b_row;
    int a_col,b_col;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i += period){
        if (i + period > len){
            period = len - i;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < period; j ++){
            a = text[i+(j/2)];
            b = text[i+((period+j)/2)];

            /*if (index(key,a) == NULL || index(key,b) == NULL) break;*/
113         a_ind = (int)(index(key,a) - key);
114         b_ind = (int)(index(key,b) - key);
            a_row = a_ind / 5;
            b_row = b_ind / 5;
            a_col = a_ind % 5;
            b_col = b_ind % 5;
            if (j % 2 == 0){
                result[i+j] = key[5*a_row + b_col];
            } else {
                result[i+j] = key[5*a_col + b_row];
            }
        }
    }
    result[i] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

Comment: The lines of code referenced would be useful...

Comment: Added a snippet of bifidcrack.c and listed which are lines 113 and 114. Hope that helps!

Comment: Need to know what 'index' is. If it's not returning a `char *`, then yeah, it's a compile error.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How would I go about finding what it is? I don't have any C experience unfortunately. I hadn't noticed that the link I posted is now down, but it's still accessible through TWBM if it helps: http://web.archive.org/web/20151018181750/http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/stochastic-searching/cryptanalysis-bifid-cipher/

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that on line 113 and 114 of bifidcrack.c a pointer is being used to subtract from a non-pointer element. Without seeing the actual code, since the page is unavailable, I would guess that there is an improperly dereferenced pointer.

Something similar to this scenario

```
int * pointer_int = 5;
int non_pointer = 4;
```

This is what it would currently look like

```
int new_int = non_pointer - pointer_int;
```

Though it should look like this

```
int new_int = non_pointer - (int*)pointer_int;
```

You will have to open the file and go to those lines to see about altering them.

Comment: Sorry, the link has only just gone down and I hadn't noticed. I've added part of bifidcrack.c and the rest can be accessed through TWBM: http://web.archive.org/web/20151018181750/http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/stochastic-searching/cryptanalysis-bifid-cipher/
I have no knowledge of C but I'll try and have a fiddle with the code. Thanks for advice.

Comment: Because key is a pointer, whatever index is returning needs to also be a pointer. That is your error. You may try adding (char*) before the last key in each of those lines

Comment: Thanks, but I added the cast and it returned the same error when compiling.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/index

index returns a pointer if it matches a character though if it doesn't match a character, it returns NULL.... try throwing some if statements to handle this. Something like if(index(key,a) != NULL){a_ind = (int)(index(key,a) - key);}
else{ DO SOMETHING TO HANDLE IT}
And the same for line 114. Depending on the compiler it can be overly cautious.

Answer (score 0):

The code you reference has depreciated code and will not compile without changing from index (depreciated POSIX) to strchr(current) and casting as appropriate.

example:

```
 // https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strchr/
 a_ind = (int)(strchr(key, (int)a) - (const char *)key );
 b_ind = (int)(strchr(key, (int)b) - (const char *)key );
```

compile: `cl /EHcs bifidcrack.c scoreText.c`